# Azure Functions Core Tools - Make VS2022 use specific version

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions

Is there some way I can configure Visual Studio 2022 to use a specific version of the Azure Functions Core Tools and stop it from keep auto-updating the version?

#### Update

So I've managed to run some earlier versions of `func.exe` with earlier working builds of my code but I just keep getting error:

```
A host error has occurred during startup operation '00e57aab-bb85-42eb-8b4a-13e0c279b8ef'.
[2022-04-13T12:17:34.919Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask: Unable to find an Azure Storage connection string to use for this binding.
[2022-04-13T12:17:34.928Z] Using the default storage provider: AzureStorage.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')
```

An update to VS2022 must have blown something low-level up in my local environment.

Comment: Are you trying to Stop Updating the Function Tools?

Comment: AFAIK, while creating the Azure Function by default it takes the recent version of Core Tools present in your system. Either `upgrade` or `Downgrade` the Core tool Version from the default.

Comment: @DelliganeshS-MT It looks like either the latest version of VS2022 or the Azure Functions Core Tools have blown up my local debugging experience so I'm trying to get back to a working local build.

Comment: you can downgrade your core tools version in NuGet package manager.

Comment: Yeah I've managed to run a couple of earlier releases of `func.exe` but still get the error I've added to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pin to the **specific version** of **Azure Functions core tools** in the Visual Studio 2022. It will **not** let you **auto update**.

**Whatever the recent version you installed, that will be picked by VS.**
[image]

**Example**:
[image]

Here when you select **.NET 6**, it will create project on **AFCT Version 4**, if **.NET 3**, it will create project on **AFCT Version 3 (v3)**.

[image]

But it will **not update** automatically. You can run **.NET 3.1** project on **v3** until there are any specific bindings or code requires update of **AFCT Version 4**.

**It will just notify you there are some updates on Azure Functions Core Tools Package in your project/solution.**

> Note: AFCT - Azure Functions Core Tools

Whereas in **VS Code**, even though there are **multiple versions of Azure Functions core Tools installed**. At the **beginning of project creation, you can select/pin the Specific Version of Azure Functions Core tools.**

[image]
[image]

Later, it will notify there is an update on **Azure Functions Core Tools** Package that either you can **accept update or ignore** if you want to work on **specified version**.

Answer (score 0):

I have been updating an old function app that was running framework 2.2. Converted to 6.0 with fresh nugets including the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions of 4.2.0 but it still runs Azure Functions Core Tools version 2.7.3188. I wanted to stick with Visual Studio. I had already downloaded the correct tools and installed them on my PC. However it didn't have any effect immediately. It finally started running the correct tools after a reboot. Also ensure that in your csproj you have the right AzureFunctionsVersion - for 4x tools have v4 etc:

```
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
```

This also could help:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
      <UseNETCoreGenerator>true</UseNETCoreGenerator>
  </PropertyGroup>
```